# What is the fastest single-engine civil turboprop aircraft with cabin seating?

Tags: aircraft-performance, turboprop

I was having a discussion with some friends about general aviation aircraft with cabin-class seating. We were discussing cruise speeds and there were some "shop talk opinions" flying around about what the fastest single-engine turboprop in general aviation is. I'm curious to know who holds the title.

Comment: Fastest single-engine prop? P-51 Mustang, of course! Oh, _turbo_ prop, GA, cabin seating. sigh...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The TBM 900 holds the title of [fastest single engine turboprop](https://www.eaa.org/en/airventure/eaa-airventure-news-and-multimedia/eaa-airventure-news/eaa-airventure-oshkosh/2014-07-31-TBM_900_is_the_Worlds_Fastest_Certified_Single-engine_Turboprop) for [civilian planes](http://hartzellprop.com/flying-magazine-names-fastest-aircraft/). It has a top cruise speed of 330 knots at FL280.

[image: TBM 900]

Answer (score 13):

In civil GA aircraft, [TBM 900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCATA_TBM) is the fastest one with a top cruise speed of 330 knots (at 28000 ft).

[image: TBM 900]

Source: flightclub.jalopnik.com

However, if one considers [*all* single engined turboprop aircraft](http://www.flyingmag.com/aircraft/fastest-aircraft-top-performers-their-class?page=0,4), the fastest is the [Pilatus PC-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-21), with a top speed of 370 knots.

[image: Pilatus PC 21]

"[Pilatus pc-21 hb-hzc lands arp](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pilatus_pc-21_hb-hzc_lands_arp.jpg#/media/File:Pilatus_pc-21_hb-hzc_lands_arp.jpg)" by Adrian Pingstone ([Arpingstone](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Arpingstone)) - Own work. Licensed under Public Domain via [Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

Answer (score 2):

A one-off homebuilt stole the title from the PC21, the 850SHP two seat modified Lancair Legacy "Turbulence" cruises around 375-380 knots.

[image: Lancair Legacy "Turbulence"]

Comment: Is this plane currently sitting at KPAO in California? I swear to god it was tied down next to my trainer when I was getting my license.

Answer (score 1):

The [Lancair Evolution](http://www.evolutionaircraft.com/aircraft/) comes to mind coming in at 300Kts

[image]
([source](https://aerospaceblog.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/lancair-evolution/))

The [Pilatus PC-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilatus_PC-21) comes in at 370Kts but those are mainly military training planes so it may not fall under the GA space.